# PHPMailer authentication issue xoauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, phpmailer

I am using Google Business Apps for emails, and trying to send emails through PHPMailer. Now there is an issue with the SSL certificate so I have to turn off the SSL verification, but this errors is thrown up:

```
Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Now my host isn't particularly helpful as its saying I need to use the correct email/pass, but that's not the way it works as we have to create an App via Google Developer and the connection is verified.

I am wondering if XOAUTH2 needs to be installed to the server? I have access to cPanel, but can't find the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) that the error links you to.

I'd bet that your ISP is intercepting your traffic and redirecting you to their own mail server, which will fail to match gmail's SSL certificate, and also lacks gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication scheme.

You should pay attention to *why* you're getting these errors - certificate verification is there to protect you and when it fails a check it's telling you that someone is intercepting your traffic and trying to MITM you - and by disabling it you've already given away your gmail credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Synchro, I have gone over the troubleshooting guide over and over again.

My setup is going through Cloudflare, on a dedicated SSL certificate. I am getting the typical 'stream_socket_enable_crypto():' error which I can't fix and neither can my host. So I am trying to disable the SSL verification, but that brings up this error.

Right now I am not worried about security so much, I am worried about getting my emails sending through the server as it is extremely urgent.

Comment: Everything I've said is in the guide. You've not posted enough debug output to diagnose anything more accurately.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my comment, and here is a pastebin with the full debug output: https://pastebin.com/2HcsD1VL

Comment: It shows exactly what I said: you're requesting to connect to `smtp.gmail.com`, but it's connecting to `eros.thewebhostserver.com` instead, so that's where your SSL failure is coming from, and that server doesn't support XOAUTH2, just as I said. Is this really that hard?

Comment: My apologies if I come across like a total idiot, I am completely clueless to email/server issues like these. I see what you mean in regards to this section: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#firewall-redirection, I am just not understanding where I need to go as people seem to push the problem onto different areas, I am in contact with my host and cloudflare. I have upgraded my SSL certificate to a dedicated one with a proper host name as I thought that was part of the problem.

Comment: Changing your cert won't help - that's for the connection between a browser and your site - the problem connection here is on the back-end, between your server and gmail, where it appears that your ISP is intercepting your outbound SMTP traffic. They must have a means of letting you send email - either by removing their interception or by providing a mail relay service (what GoDaddy does), so it's definitely your ISP you should be asking and checking their docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141577/discussion-between-jamie000012-and-synchro).

Comment: I have selected you as the right answer, Thanks again for your patience and help, they don't have any docs on this issue and are sadly not very helpful (like telling me to double check my email and password is correct.., and that any ssl issues should be me contacting cloudflare..) I guess that's my fault for not going with a major host. 

Looks like my options continue to be badgering and arguing with my host, or transfer to a different company.

Comment: Final comment, it's actually been fixed now. Copying your comment over to the host seems to have done the trick, they checked the firewall and fixed it. Can't thank you enough, have a great week.